# Cross compilation of packages for ARM architecture

Tags: c#, .net-core, compilation, raspberry-pi

I have built a C# .NET Core application in visual studio using some nuGet packages:

https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net
https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp

Now I would like to make it work in a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian. How can I do that? Is it necessary to download source code from those projects and recompile it on the target? Is there a way to cross compile it on my pc? I have little experience in cross compilation.

In this case would it be better to use Windows IoT on the Raspberry?

On the Raspberry I have already installed the .NETCore environment so I can run a C# application without external libraries.

Comment: There is .net core distributive for ARM, [read this blogpost](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingTheNETCore2xSDKOnARaspberryPiAndBlinkingAnLEDWithSystemDeviceGpio.aspx) how to install it. `akka.net` should work fine (didn't try though), but `opencvsharp` does not seem to have port for ARM that's why I doubt it will work on RPi. [Here](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/issues/388) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350733/compile-opencv-3-for-windows-10-iot-core-arm-raspberry-pi) is a discussion how to build it for ARM, so you may still try doing that. Good luck.

Comment: @fenixil I tried to build but it didn't worked and I have a small knowledge about building big libraries in Linux. Now I am considering this board https://up-board.org/upcore/specifications/ that has intel processor.